# Spring NoClassDefFoundError org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException when adding <context:component-scan ...> in the config

Tags: java, spring

I'm writing a simple Spring 3.1 test, I'm getting an exception when adding the following line in my config:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.software.shared" />
```

Here's the exception:

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-config.xml]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.software.shared.PersonBeanTest.<init>(PersonBeanTest.java:15)
at com.software.shared.PersonBeanTest.main(PersonBeanTest.java:31)
```

I don't get what's going on. If I remove the line, the exception dissappears, but Autowiring doesn't work.

I have all the jars in the spring 3.1 RELEASE distribution, on my class path, including org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar and I checked that it contains that file.
This is the code in the main method:

```
package com.software.shared;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class PersonBeanTest {

    public PersonBeanTest() {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
        //System.out.println("Name=" + ((PersonBean) (context.getBean("personBean"))).getName());
    }

    private PersonBean myBean;

    public PersonBean getMyBean() {
        return myBean;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setMyBean(PersonBean myBean) {
        this.myBean = myBean;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonBeanTest test = new PersonBeanTest();
        System.out.println("Name=" + test.getMyBean().getName());
    }
}
```

Here's the Spring config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.software" /> -->
    <!-- Register Annotation-based Post Processing Beans -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scan context package for any eligible annotation configured beans. -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.software.shared" />

    <bean id="personBean" class="com.software.shared.PersonBean">
        <property name="name" value="MyName" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I start the app by right clicking on this class and clicking "Run As -> Java Application". 
Any ideas on why I get the exception?

Comment: Might seem like a silly question but have you defined the PersonBean class? Also, try annotating the actual field not the setter - thats where I usually annotate my spring beans

Comment: I have defined it, yes :) I didn't post it here because it's just a java bean. I tried annotating the actual field but the exception still exists.

Comment: If you're using Maven, post your pom.xml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are trying to make spring scan class **PersonBeanTest** in package **com.software.shared**, but meanwhile you are creating the same application context in the constructor of **PersonBeanTest**, I guess this is the root cause of the exception.

try to scan some other package:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="some.other.package" />
```

and test it with the following code snippet to see if it works

```
public class PersonBeanTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
        assertNotNull(context.getBean(PersonBean.class));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this happened because of a StackOverflowError. In some Spring catch block, the FatalBeanException subclass initialization failed again because of the current very long stack, leading to a NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: I had similar issue. While migrating configurations I made a case where two beans were dependent on each other. That caused a race during beans initialization. It was extremely difficult to find as the error didn't really say a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think When your ApplicationContext loads at startup it tries to instantiate the Bean PersonBeanTest using its default constructor inside which you are creating another ApplicationContext which will again try to instantiate the same bean.This process goes on for infinite time finally throwing an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem under different circumstances.  I'm not sure why this happens, but you should be able to find the original exception by putting a breakpoint inside `AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory` where the `BeanCreationException` is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your spring-config.xml into the classpath.