# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException

Tags: maven, jax-ws, tomcat8, spring-4, hibernate-5.x

I am building a JAX-WS web service in Java 8 and using Spring 4.2.6 and Hibernate 5.1 with it. But when I am deploying my project on tomcat, I am encountering following exception. I have googled the same and none of the stackoverflow post has been helpful.

**Exception Stack**

```
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

May 28, 2016 10:42:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
May 28, 2016 10:42:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/MavenEmployee] startup failed due to previous errors
May 28, 2016 10:42:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
May 28, 2016 10:42:25 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat May 28 22:42:14 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
May 28, 2016 10:42:25 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
WARNING: Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat May 28 22:42:14 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:415)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:975)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:559)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4776)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5390)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.maven.ws</groupId>
<artifactId>MavenEmployee</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>Maven WS</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Library from java.net, integrate Spring with JAX-WS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
                <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>



<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate library dependency start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate library dependency end -->

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>MavenEmployee</finalName>
</build>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core" xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core.xsd http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">

    <wss:binding url="/employee">
        <wss:service>
            <ws:service bean="#employeeWS" />
        </wss:service>
    </wss:binding>

    <bean id="employeeWS" class="com.maven.spring.EmployeeWSImpl">
        <property name="employee" ref="employeePOJO" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="employeePOJO" class="com.maven.spring.Employee">
        <property name="empID" value="1234" />
        <property name="name" value="Steve" />
        <property name="designation" value="HOD"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@schoolpc:1721:orcl2"></property>
        <property name="username" value="ADMIN"></property>
        <property name="password" value="admin123"></property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="employeeDAO" class="com.maven.spring.EmployeeDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**employee.hbm.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.maven.spring.Employee" table="EMP_RCRD">
        <meta attribute="clas-description">
            Employee POJO
        </meta>
        <id name="empID" type="string" column="EMP_ID">
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string" column="EMP_NAME"></property>
        <property name="designation" type="string" column="EMP_DESIG"></property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**web.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>MavenEmployee</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/employee</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Register Spring Listener -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

**Project Structure**

**[image: Project Structure]**

I have been struggling with this error for whole day. I don't know what am I missing here.

**UPDATE**
 The error comes upon execution of following line in my java file.

**ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");**

Comment: Check if the problem is same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626819/spring-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-beans-fatalbeanexception-when-ad

Comment: @chaitan64arun I have already referred the above link but it is not helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem got resolved by using following line of code

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");
```

**instead of**

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

I still don't know the reason why it worked. Will appreciate if somebody could explain this.